# Java Export to CSV - Replace HTML Entity

Tags: java, html-entities, export-to-csv, printwriter

I am using Java to export one CSV. Its a lotus notes based app, and I am writing the output to the output printwriter object.

```
pw.println("Content-Type: text/text; charset=iso-8859-1");
pw.println("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv");
pw.println("Content-Language: en");
```

I am writing a line like this :

```
IMAZ-5NSAMF;ABCD;Europe;XYZ;;NA;(“CA 2010”);
```

The quotes mark towards the end is the weird double quotes, which is little bit slanting one. But my output is converting those quotes into its HTML entity and showing as (“CA 2010”)

I debugged and just before writing to printwriter also I am having quote marks, but after that it is getting converted to HTML Entity. Am I doing something wrong with the charset of the content type.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers, Anoop

Comment: You could try text/csv or text/plain as Content-Type.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I tried both. But no luck :(

Comment: Can you show the code to "print a line" ?

Comment: its the usual printWriter.write("IMAZ-5NSAMF;ABCD;Europe;XYZ;;NA;(“CA 2010”)");

Comment: If you are using standard HttpServlet, there is no reason the content be converted to HTML entities. Have you a Filter or something else in conflict?